# unexpected value of a wide char

Tags: c

Given this program, it prints `-43632 1`. It is expected the 2nd value to be 1, but I do not understand how did it compute the negative value.

Where in the ISO9899 standard it's explained how to compute this ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x = L'\uaaaa9', y = L'\uaaaa';

main()
{
  printf("%d %d\n", x-0xaaa9, y-0xaaa9);
}
```

EDIT: writing this absurd program I try to understand when it's valid to have a constant-char made by many characters, because in the Standard it's allowed in the syntax of the language (see appendix A for a summary of the BNF) multiple characters in a single constant-char.

Comment: Why not use `wchar_t`?

Comment: almost sure wchar_t is interpreted as int, nothing is lost.  I try to understand how the computation is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where in standard - nowhere. Your program is not strictly-conforming:

```
% gcc test.c -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c11
test.c:2:9: error: character constant too long for its type [-Werror]
 int x = L'\uaaaa9', y = L'\uaaaa';
```

`L'\uaaaa'` is one character followed by another character `L'9'`.

And [C11 6.4.4.4p11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p11) says:

> The value of a wide character constant containing more than one multibyte character or a single multibyte character that maps to multiple members of the extended execution character set, or containing a multibyte character or escape sequence not represented in the extended execution character set, is **implementation-defined.**

[The behaviour of GCC in the case of integer character constants is](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-defined-behavior.html#Implementation-defined-behavior):

> The compiler evaluates a multi-character character constant a character at a time, shifting the previous value left by the number of bits per target character, and then or-ing in the bit-pattern of the new character truncated to the width of a target character. The final bit-pattern is given type int, and is therefore signed, regardless of whether single characters are signed or not. If there are more characters in the constant than would fit in the target int the compiler issues a warning, and the excess leading characters are ignored.

However, the more I read the standard, I get the feeling that the case of multicharacter wide character constants is *not* properly documented by the GCC, since the documentation just mentions that the character constants of type `int`, yet `L''` constants should produce the value `wchar_t`.

In any case, the value that you see, `-43632` comes from the fact that `L'\uaaaa9'` has the value `L'9'` on your platform, i.e. `(wchar_t)0x39`; and `)0x39 - 0xaaa9` will result in -43632.

---

To sum it up, never rely in multicharacter wide constants producing anything sensible, as the standard doesn't back it up. Multicharacter integer constants are dubious too, because, while they might be useful, their value is still implementation-defined, and not all implementations might agree.

Comment: The Standard defined the syntax of a char-constant as a kleene-star of a char (that can be unicode in particular).  Why does the Standard allow many chars in a single constant-char?  And in which situation does it make sense to have a char-constant made of many chars?

Comment: Actually this is why I did write this absurd program, in order to try to understand this.

Comment: @alinsoar it is not defined by the standard what the behaviour *is*, but since character constants are of type *int*, and implementations already have used it to specify packed bytes such as magic numbers like `'JFIF'`.